# Bash calling cmd /c %ProgramFiles(x86)%\

Tags: bash, msysgit, cmd

From a bash script (bash from msysgit), I'd like to run MS VB 2010 Express compilation but none of the following lines works:

```
$ $PROGRAMFILES/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 10.0\\Common7\\ide\\vbexpress.exe path/to/solution.sln /build
```

Results in `sh.exe": C:\Program: No such file or directory`

```
$ "$PROGRAMFILES/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 10.0\\Common7\\ide\\vbexpress.exe" path/to/solution.sln /build
```

Results in `sh.exe": C:\Program Files (x86)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 10.0\Common7\ide\vbexpress.exe: No such file or directory`

```
$ cmd /c "$PROGRAMFILES(X86)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 10.0\\Common7\\ide\\vbexpress.exe" path/to/solution.sln /build
```

This will open the cmd-shell only, as cmd seems not to recognize the argument to the parameter `/c`

```
$ cmd "/c $PROGRAMFILES(X86)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 10.0\\Common7\\ide\\vbexpress.exe" path/to/solution.sln /build
```

Error Message: Command `C:\Program`" not found

```
$ /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 10.0/Common7/IDE/vbexpress.exe IOS\\IOS.sln /build
```

Kinda works, but though it starts VB Express it complains that `C:\Program Files (x86)/Git/build` could not be load - clearly the shell expands `/build` to a path. And this solution is flawed as I would like to use an environment variable to distinguish between 32-bit and 64-bit installations of Windows.

What's the correct way of escaping the path separators and space to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I do not have this particular software, I believe that something like this works:

```
"$PROGRAMFILES/Microsoft Visual Studio/10.0/Common7/IDE/vbexpress.exe" 'IOS\IOS.sln' '//build'
```

I tried it to invoke some other software like:

```
"$PROGRAMFILES/Internet Explorer/iexplore" 'T:\public_html\index.html'
```

Comment: If that's the only problem, then doubling the slashes on /build should work.

Comment: I modified the answer to reflect the doubled slashes.